# Merge two different array

Tags: php, arrays

I am confused with array.

What I want to do is two merge two array, but this kind of the two array are different:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sud] => 60
            [sad] => Array
                (
                    [incharge] => Perusahaan
                    [perusahaan_id] => 1
                    [barang_id] => 3
                    [gudang_id] => 2
                    [stock] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sud] => 23
            [sad] => Array
                (
                    [incharge] => Perusahaan
                    [perusahaan_id] => 1
                    [barang_id] => 4
                    [gudang_id] => 1
                    [stock] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I want to move the array of [sud] into [sad] array, and named it as quantity.

This is my codes which generate the array above:

```
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($q->result() as $row => $rows)
                    {
                        $data[] = $rows;
                        $stock[] = $rows->stock;
                    }
            }           
            $i = -1;
            foreach ($update as $updates)
                {
                    $i++; 
                    $test3['sud'] = $stock[$i];
                    $test3['sad'] =  $updates; 
                    $happy[] = $test3; 
                }
                    print_r ($happy);
```

What I want to do here actually is to check if the number of array `[stock] => value` is not bigger than the number in array [sud].

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to change it like this:

```
 if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($q->result() as $row => $rows)
                    {
                        $data[] = $rows;
                        $stock[] = $rows->stock;
                    }
            }           
            $i = -1;
            foreach ($update as $updates)
                {
                    $i++; 

                    $test3['sad'] =  $updates; 
                    $test3['sad']['quantity'] =  $stock[$i]; 
                    $happy[] = $test3; 
                }
                    print_r ($happy);
```